# How to remove rejected Facebook events from Google Calendar?

Tags: facebook, google-calendar-api

I synced my google calendar with facebook events by subscribing to a proper URL:

```
webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=xxxx&key=xxxx
```

Unfortunately when someone invites me to an event and I reject it (remove myself from the list of invited people) the event still appears on my Google Calendar.

It's quite tolerable when the event lasts 1 hour, but it's VERY annoying when it's duration is a week or longer - it messes the whole display.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem programming related, and should be directed a FB end user support instead.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the only way I have been able to do this is to unsubscribe from the calendar under Google Calendar Settings, and manually add the Facebook events as required